# Trying to pipe steamcmd output to yad

Tags: steam, gui, pipe, zenity

In order to run a server through steam I need to run this command from it's install directory, this works, and has worked for quite some time.

```
./srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers $play +host_workshop_collection 615323401 -authkey [AUTHKEY] +map gm_$map
```

this is a slightly modified version that I use for a script that was via CLI and works. Only recently however I've decided to dabble in yad and create it a GUI. I have everything working except this. What happens when I pipe this into

```
yad --list --column="Server Log"
```

Is it gets the first 3 lines to yad. and then all the remaining output is in a terminal. I am currently doing

```
./srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers $play +host_workshop_collection 615323401 -authkey [AUTHKEY] +map gm_$map | yad --list --column="Server Log"
```

If anyone has any experience or insight in how I may get this working it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the terminal output of when you run both commands?